# Swift pointer arithmetic and dereferencing; converting some C-like map code to Swift

Tags: ios, pointers, swift, dereference

I have this little bit of Swift code that does not seem to be working...

```
// earlier, in Obj C...
    typedef struct _Room {
        uint8_t *map;
        int width;
        int height;
    } Room;
```

A Room is part of a stab at a roguelike game if you're curious. I'm trying to rewrite a couple of parts in Swift. Here's the code that appears broken, and what I hope I am doing as comments:

```
let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(room.map) // grab a pointer to the map out of the room struct
let offset = (Int(room.width) * Int(point.y)) + Int(point.x) // calculate an int offset to the location I am interested in examining
let locationPointer = ptr + offset // pointer advances to point to the offset I want
var pointValue = ptr.memory // What I used to get with *ptr
```

Something is wrong here because simple tests show the value of pointValue is not what I know I am looking at on the map, having set a very simple location (1, 1) to a known value. It seems pretty obvious that Swift is not supposed to be doing this kind of thing but it's a conversion with the aim of learning the Way of Swift when I know the syntax well enough.

I expect the error is in the swift code - since this was all working in the objective C version. Where's the error?

Comment: +1 for very clearly stated problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are assigning `locationPointer` to point to the new location, but still using `ptr` in the next line, and the value of `ptr` has not been changed.  Change your last line to:

```
var pointValue = locationPointer.memory
```

or you could change your pointer to a `var` and advance it:

```
var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(room.map) // grab a pointer to the map out of the room struct
let offset = (Int(room.width) * Int(point.y)) + Int(point.x) // calculate an int offset to the location I am interested in examining
ptr = ptr + offset // pointer advances to point to the offset I want
var pointValue = ptr.memory // What I used to get with *ptr
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Don't down vote without a comment. That isn't helping anyone.

Comment: Argh! That's the kind of mistake you get for programming late. Thanks, I will try it and accept later.

Comment: Or, you can use ```MemoryLayout<_Room>.size``` instead ```(Int(room.width) * Int(point.y)) + Int(point.x)```

Comment: @isnullxbh, I don't think the size of the `_Room` `struct` matters.  This calculation needs to vary depending on the values of `room.width` and the specific `point.x` and `point.y` that is being accessed.

Comment: @vacawama, yes, of course, you're right. Excuse me :)